# I don't know how to add rows to a dataframe after 'append' was removed/deprecated. I'm using pandas version 2.0.2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, append

```
my_columns=['Ticker', 'Stock Price', 'Market Capitalization',' Number of Shares to Buy']
kushdf= pd.DataFrame(columns=my_columns)
kushdf
```

I want to add this data to kushdf:

```
Ticker: AAPL
Stock Price: 192.4600
Market Cap: 3027145851000
Number of Shares to Buy: 'N/A'
```

`.append` isn't working and when `.concat` is used its showing `'RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded'`

What do I do?

Comment: Store your data in a regular list or dict then use `pd.concat` or `pd.DataFrame` to create your dataframe. Don't create an empty dataframe then append or concat new records, it's a bad an inefficient practice.